# Is it possible to block websites from refreshing themselves

Tags: google-chrome, browser

There are some websites (for example ynet.co.il  - Hebrew), that keep refreshing themselves every X minutes.

Is there a way to block them from doing so ?

(I use win XP with google chrome)

Comment: May I ask, why you want to do this? Perhaps there is another way to help you with this.

Comment: To stop spam websites giving me adds.

Answer (score 10):

Sites may also implement [auto-refresh through plain HTML using the META tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). Almost all the popular browsers have some way of detecting META refreshes.

In Internet Explorer 8: go to Tools > Internet options > Security tab > Custom Level button > Miscellaneous category > check the Disable radio button for the "Allow META REFRESH" option.

In Firefox (I tested in ver 3.6): go to Tools > Options.. and in the Advanced section's General tab, check the "Warn me when web sites try to redirect or reload the page" checkbox in the Accessibility panel.

In Opera, you can go to Preferences > Advanced > Network and uncheck "Enable automatic redirection" checkbox

Comment: Thank you Mvark - what do I do with chorme ? :)

Comment: @Tal - it doesn't look like there's an option in Chrome 5.

Comment: AFAIK, Chrome does not natively support any settings to block META refreshes nor are there any related Extensions currently. I also tried (http://jaxov.com/2009/11/install-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome-easily/) a few Greasemonkey scripts (http://userscripts.org/tags/metarefresh) but they did not work for me.

Comment: It is possible now to prevent auto-refresh in Chrome. Within Dev tools, click on the three vertical dots icon on the right side of the menu, slide down to "More Tools" & select "Network conditions" from the sub menu. In the "Network conditions" tab, choose "Offline" in the dropdown against the "Network Throttling" option. This way you can conditionally control AJAX requests for a single website. For screenshots, check this - http://mvark.blogspot.com/2017/10/how-to-prevent-ajax-requests-within-web.html

Answer (score 2):

Turning off javascript should work.

A bit of an extreme/crude method, but should be effective.

Comment: There is no NoScript extension for Chrome, but you can selectively block JS using Chrome's built-in function http://a.imageshack.us/img820/5060/pic20100902081042.png.

Comment: Thanks MGOwen and Marek Grzenkowicz. That did the job. Thanks, German

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Try going to vk.com with JavaScript off.

Answer (score 2):

Others have had this issue with Chrome. It [does not appear possible](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=29a4333f35df79e3&hl=en) to disable meta refreshes in Chrome. I couldn't find a bug report for Chrome that directly mentions this, but [this one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42364) appears related. You might try filing a new bug report.

Comment: I found an open bug report for this [here](https://crbug.com/63107). You can pull that up and star the issue to help it get additional traction. *(Please don't add "me too!" comments to the issue - at best it will annoy those subscribed to the issue, and at worst it may cause the devs to lock out the comment box for all non-devs.)*

Comment: Thanks! Interesting that it was opened shortly after this question was posted and is still open eight years later...

Comment: Yeah. Looks like it only really started to first get any traction in spring of 2017. There are also a handful of more-or-less duplicates that have been closed, probably for being less well explained (or confrontationally phrased) and so not identified as duplicates - I searched for all issues (open or closed) containing the string "meta refresh" (with quotes), and found this near the bottom of the results (I believe they were sorted by open date, by default).